# Finding a href links with simple dom

Tags: php, html, dom, simpledom

I am **simplephpdom** using to get `a` href links values with this code :

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) $array[] = $element->href . '<br>';
```

Now, the problem is that if the link , is starting with slash (/) the link will be not valid !

How can i have valid links ?

For example , the link is like this :

```
<a href="/news45454.html">Test link</a>
```

if i use phpsimpledom code, i will have :

```
/news45454.html
```

But, i want to have :

```
http://example.com/news45454.html
```

How to get this?

Can we test , if the link was starting with slash , then add site url to it ?!
How ?

Comment: Can't you simply join string with http:\/\/domain address to given link if it starts with slash?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk not really. can u give a code ?

Comment: Like `if('/' == $link[0]) { $link = 'http://example.com'.$link; }` ?

Comment: It's not just when it starts with a `/`. `href="foo.html"` has the same problem, doesn't it?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk yeah, but should use foreach loop to work for all array, if possible, i want to detect external URLs after adding the main URL. can u give the simple code please ?

Comment: @Barmar You are right. but that doesn't matter dear. I just need to check 2 things : 1- The problem above(adding url) 2- Detect and delete all other external domains. Can u code it please ? :X

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You wrote a simple `foreach` loop in your question, how hard it is to move my code and test for other variations?

Comment: See the URL merging function here: http://blog.amnuts.com/2011/09/26/merge-two-urls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to test if the HREF element is a valid full URL. If the validation passes, you can go ahead and add it to the array. However, if the validation fails, you need to concatenate the basename (which should be website's domain).

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        // Valid URL, add to array.
        $array[] = $element->href . '<br>'; 
    } else {
        // URL is invalid, add basename.
        $array[] = basename($url) . $element->href . '<br>';
    }
}
```

This may need a bit of tweaking for other cases (such as `<a href="#">`) but it should work for the situation you outlined.

Comment: @Cab hmm... what went wrong on your side? I can try to troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

To delete slashes Use:

```
string stripcslashes ( string $str )
```

Also see the [PHP Manual: stripcslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripcslashes.php)